# How to get text boxes on click of tab content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As you can see in the below fiddle.

On click of tab1 & tab2 we get tab1 info & tab2 info.

So now when we click on **tab1 info** I want to get one text box beside it.

Only when the user clicks on **tab1 info** the text box should appear. Hope I am clear now.

I have this 
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tonimxs/6m6f4Lhd/1/),

This might be a repeated question, kindly help me out. should I do that using jQuery or Javascript?

jQuery

```
        $('td.tab').on('click', function () {
        $('td.tab').toggleClass('not-active');
        $('td div.tab-content').toggleClass('not-active');
    });

    /* Without table */
    $('dt.tab').on('click', function () {
        $('dt.tab').toggleClass('not-active');
        $('dd.tab-content').toggleClass('not-active');
    });
```

HTML

```
        <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="tab"><div contenteditable>tab1</div></td>
        <td class="tab not-active"><div contenteditable>tab2</div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div contenteditable class="tab-content">tab1 info</div>
          <div contenteditable class="tab-content not-active">tab2 info</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <!-- Or without table because tables should not be used as layout elements -->
    <dl>
        <dt class="tab"><div contenteditable>tab1</div></dt>
        <dt class="tab not-active"><div contenteditable>tab2</div></dt>
        <dd class="tab-content">
            <div contenteditable>tab1 info</div>
        </dd>
        <dd class="tab-content not-active">
            <div contenteditable>tab2 info</div>
        </dd>
    </dl>
```

CSS

```
        dt.tab {
      float: left;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    .tab.not-active {
      color: #ccc;
    }
    .tab:hover, .tab.not-active:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: #ccc;
      color: #ff0000;
    }
    .tab-content {
      clear: both;
    }
    .tab-content.not-active {
      display: none;
    }
```

Comment: can you be more specific ?

Comment: I have no idea what your asking for...

Comment: jQuery is a library, written completely in JavaScript (aka ECMAscript).

Comment: adding an input field inside the tab-content element should do right?

Comment: As you can see in the fiddle. On click of tab1 & tab2 we get tab1 info & tab2 info.

So now when we click on **tab1 info** I want to get one text box beside it.

Only when the user clicks on **tab1 info** the text box should appear.
Hope I am clear now.

Comment: HI @KeerthanaPrabhakaran yes adding an input field inside the tab-content element will do. But it should show onClick of the **tab1 Info**

Comment: `<div contenteditable>tab1 info</div>
        <input type='text'/>` is this a solution ? or you want any thing else ?

Comment: @John674125 <div contenteditable>tab1 info <input type='text'/></div>  should do!

Comment: The text input should appear when the users click **tab1 info**

Answer (score 0):

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/6m6f4Lhd/2/) what you're looking for? Couldn't understand the question clearly but

Its better if you use `hide() and show()`

Comment: when user clicks **tab1 info**, a new text box should be displayed beside **tab1 info**

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('td.tab').on('click', function () {
    $('td.tab').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('td div.tab-content').removeClass('active');
    $('td div#' + $(this).data('tab')).addClass('active');
});

/* Without table */
$('dt.tab').on('click', function () {
    $('dt.tab').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('dd.tab-content').removeClass('active');
    $('dd#' + $(this).data('tab')).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
dt.tab {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
}
.tab:not(.active) {
  color: #ccc;
}
.tab:hover, .tab.active:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: #ff0000;
}
.tab-content {
  clear: both;
}
.tab-content:not(.active) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td data-tab="tab1-info" class="tab"><div contenteditable>tab1</div></td>
    <td data-tab="tab2-info" class="tab active"><div contenteditable>tab2</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="tab1-info" contenteditable class="tab-content active">tab1 info</div>
      <div id="tab2-info" contenteditable class="tab-content">tab2 info</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<!-- Or without table because tables should not be used as layout elements -->
<dl>
    <dt data-tab="tab1-info" class="tab"><div contenteditable>tab1</div></dt>
    <dt data-tab="tab2-info" class="tab not-active"><div contenteditable>tab2</div></dt>
    <dd id="tab1-info" class="tab-content active">
        <div contenteditable>tab1 info</div>
    </dd>
    <dd id="tab2-info" class="tab-content">
        <div contenteditable>tab2 info</div>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: May I know what change did you do. Thanks

Comment: You can check code snippet above, the main thing is I used `data-tab` to identify which `tab-info` belongs to which `tab button`

Comment: Ok, but my requirement is, 
When user clicks **tab1** -> **tab1 info** will be shown, now when user clicks **tab1 info**, a new text box should be displayed beside **tab1 info**.

Answer (score 0):

To babe exact, this is what you need. 
identify the element on which the click event is to be triggered. And then, append the input field like

```
        $(this).append('<input type="text">');
```

Here is the snippet!

```js
        $('td.tab').on('click', function () {
        $('td.tab').toggleClass('not-active');
        $('td div.tab-content').toggleClass('not-active');
    });

    /* Without table */
    $('dt.tab').on('click', function () {
        $('dt.tab').toggleClass('not-active');
        $('dd.tab-content').toggleClass('not-active');
    });
    //for table
    $('div.tab-content').on('click',function(){
        $(this).append('<input type="text">');

    });
    //for div
    $('dd div:first').on('click',function(){
        $(this).append('<input type="text">');

    });
```

```css
        dt.tab {
      float: left;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    .tab.not-active {
      color: #ccc;
    }
    .tab:hover, .tab.not-active:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: #ccc;
      color: #ff0000;
    }
    .tab-content {
      clear: both;
    }
    .tab-content.not-active {
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
      <tr>
        <td class="tab"><div contenteditable>tab1</div></td>
        <td class="tab not-active"><div contenteditable>tab2</div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div contenteditable class="tab-content">tab1 info</div>
          <div contenteditable class="tab-content not-active">tab2 info</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <!-- Or without table because tables should not be used as layout elements -->
    <dl>
        <dt class="tab"><div contenteditable>tab1</div></dt>
        <dt class="tab not-active"><div contenteditable>tab2</div></dt>
        <dd class="tab-content">
            <div contenteditable>tab1 info</div>
        </dd>
        <dd class="tab-content not-active">
            <div contenteditable>tab2 info</div>
        </dd>
    </dl>
```

Hope it helps!